# Find set of points on the grid which are at the maximal Manhattan distance from the given set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a square grid with side N. Also given a set of input points on the grid. Need to find another set of points on the grid (can be multiple) that have the maximal Manhattan distance from the given input points.

For example with `N = 4` and input `[p1:{0, 0}, p2:{3, 3}]` the output should be `[{0, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}]` with the distance equal to 3.

```
      0   1   2   3
    ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
  0 │p1 │   │   │ x │
    ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
  1 │   │   │ x │   │
    ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
  2 │   │ x │   │   │
    ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
  3 │ x │   │   │p2 │
    └───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

My first attempt was a simple brute-force iteration - for every point in the grid calculate Manhattan distance to every input point, take the minimum, and finally take the maximums from these minimums. This of course works, but slow on big N and input.

In my second attempt, I first build a kd-tree. Next iterated almost the same as before with the difference that now I don't calculate the distance to *every* input point but to the closest one (or multiple). This helped a bit but still, I was told there's a better algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a breadth-first search, starting with all the given points, to simultaneously find the distance of every cell from its nearest point.  This takes linear time and is pretty easy to code.

Then find the highest distance (or just remember it, since it will be the last one you wrote), and return all the cells with that distance.

That will work pretty well if your points aren't too sparse.  If they're separated by vast distances, then you'll need an algorithm the grows with the number of points instead of the size of the grid.  That would be based on calculating the Manhattan-distance Voronoi diagram, since all the points you want to return are on it.